# Removed messages are visible in the chat transcript ... sometimes, for some people

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat, chat-transcript

There's something weird about the removed messages in chat. I saw this in the Electrical Engineering chat. @ThePhoton said something, removed his messages so that we could only see "(removed)", but for some reason his messages were still visible in the chatlog.

You can see the message [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9901074#9901074).

I tried to reproduce this in the [sandbox](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1/sandbox) ([transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9902341#9902341)), however, the messages I removed weren't visible.

Additionally, we did some checks in the EE chat ([permalink]). Short version:

- Some users could see @ThePhoton's messages as well, some users couldn't
- @ThePhoton couldn't see his own messages in the transcript, not even a placeholder
- Other users couldn't see anything in the transcript of the sandbox
- @ThePhoton only meant to say [old-fart-stuff](/questions/tagged/old-fart-stuff)

I can't figure out what's going on here, but I don't think it's by design that I can see removed messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"(removed)" placeholders for deleted chat messages are visible in the transcript only for moderators, but the message you're linking to [has never been removed](https://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/9901074/history).

That said, removed messages are typically soft-deleted and some users (moderators, room owners, and the message author) can see the message history for a deleted message, which normally contains a copy of all revisions of the message. The chat message's history page is linked from the message action popup, which for deleted messages is the "(removed)" placeholder, so, without userscripts, the message history page is only linked from the chat room itself, unless you're a moderator.

Comment: (For completeness: the post owner, room owners, and moderators can see the history of deleted chat messages from within the live view; the deleted message was [this other one](http://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/9901070/history))

Comment: @TimStone Ah, right. Room owners. I wasn't sure if it was a straight up 10k privilege or if it had to be room owners.